# Choose random structure in LME. Should I rely on AIC?

Tags: r, aic, lme4-nlme

I want to choose the best random structure for my mixed-effects model. I have compared four models: without a random part, random intercept, random intercept and slope, and random effects:

```
gls0<-gls(time.dep~exper*group*fat*FL, method="REML",data=test)
lme1<-lme(time.dep~exper*group*fat*FL, random=~1|ring,data=test,method="REML")
lme2<-lme(time.dep~exper*group*fat*FL, random=~exper|ring,data=test,method="REML")
lme3<-lme(time.dep~1, random=~1|ring,data=test,method="REML")
AIC(gls0, lme1, lme2, lme3)

df       AIC
gls0 17  36.34948
lme1 18  38.34948
lme2 20  36.53359
lme3  3 -60.41729
```

I suppose it is obvious that random effects model has the smallest AIC, since it has no parameters in the fixed part. But this model has the highest log-likelihood as well. Does it mean that my response variable depends mostly on the random variable (and if yes, how should I interpret this result, and what should I do with other explanatory variables)? Or should I choose the model without random structure at all (but then how should I deal with pseudoreplication)?

Comment: You cannot compare AICs across models with different fixed effects when fitting with REML (i.e., the AIC of model ``lme3`` cannot be compared with that of the other models). You will have to use ``method="ML"`` if you want to compare these models with respect to their AIC.

Comment: Yes, I understand, @Wolfgang. But then how can I compare other models using ML? Because as far as I know when I compare models with different random structure I should use REML. However, it doesn' solve the problem, as with ML I get: gls0 -58.82797; lme1 -56.82797; lme2 -65.54590; lme3 -66.98719

Comment: I am not sure I understand your confusion now. Based on the AIC, model ``lme3`` has the lowest value, so this would be the preferred model based on this criterion, but closely followed by ``lme2``.

Comment: Sorry, @Wolfgang, I'll try to be more clear. 1. I thought I have to select the best random structure using REML (Zuur 2009). But I know, that REML is good only when the fixed structure is stable. That was my first confusing point. 2. Probably, it is a stupid question, but how to interpret that the best model is random effects model? Can I still work with lme2 or I should simply say, that my optimal model is lme3? 3. According to REML estimation gls model is better than lme models. And the plot of residuals also looks better. But I do know, that my data have pseudoreplications. How could it be?

Comment: I would not even bother with all this model selection stuff. The model with random intercepts/slopes seems to be ok and, if I understand you correctly, is based on a priori considerations (i.e., due to pseudoreplications). So, I would just leave that part alone. I also wouldn't start fiddling around with the fixed effects part. Specify your model a priori and report that. Of course, you are free to do anything beyond that, but this is exploratory and should be declared as such.

Comment: @Wolfgang, thank you! I think I'll do as you suggested. Although I still do not understand how I've got such results (they seem strange for me). And also the difference between lme and lmer is rather big. I suppose all this happened because I have small N (37).